# call controller from a view

Tags: php, joomla, model-view-controller

While developing a custom component I want to make a call to the controller from the view after the default template of view is rendered on the screen.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

After the view is loaded, you can call the controller via a couple of methods. Either pass your parameters to it via a URL (url/controller?param=value&another_param=value) or you can do it without reloading the page by using AJAX and passing GET parameters to the URL that you call with the AJAX.